# Pass Arguments To Extension

Tags: php, silverstripe

The desired result is:

```
class SomeExtension extends Extension{

    public static function add_to_class($class, $extensionClass, $args = null){
        //$args = ["some_key"=>"some value"];
    }
}
```

My `config.yml` is (incorrectly formatted) like so:

```
SomeClass:
  extensions:
   - SomeExtension
      some_key: "some value"
```

This yml doesn't parse, but is it possible to inject args into an extension like this? I can't find any documentation on how to use the 3rd parameter of `Extension::add_to_class`

Comment: You want to use 3rd parameter. But before you have to use first and second. Maybe you can share some more details\code because now it's not clear what are you asking?

Comment: I would love to share details, but I have none. I don't know the slightest as to how I am meant to use the yml (or if it is even possible) to pass arguments to the `Extension::add_to_class` method. I essentially want something to show up in `$args`

Comment: Is add_to_class is factory method? Why is it static?

Comment: @Ziumin it's part of SilverStripe's `Extension` class

Comment: So it is not Symfony2, but SilverStripe question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass the arguments in parentheses, like so:

```
SomeClass:
  extensions:
    - "SomeExtension('arg1','arg2')"
```